# Make the special character stay in the index java

Tags: java

I have a code that can make the word reversed word by word, for example, the input is "stack overflow" the output will be "kcats wolfrevo" but the problem is when I input "stack, overflow." the output will be ",kcats .wolfrevo" not "kcats, wolfrevo.".

Is there any way that makes the special character stay in his index? 
I only know java programming basics.

My codes:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a Paragraph: ");
    String str = input.nextLine();

    String[] Words = new String[countWords(str)];
    int temp = str.length()-1;

    for (int j = 0; j < countWords(str); j++) {

        String reverse = "";
        loop:
        for (int i=temp;i>=0;i--) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                temp=temp-1;
                break;
            }
            temp=temp-1;

            reverse = reverse + str.charAt(i);
        }
        Words[j]=reverse;

    }
    for (int i = countWords(str)-1;i>=0;i--) {
        System.out.print(Words[i]+" ");
    }

}

protected static int countWords(String str) {
    int count = 0;
    if (!(" ".equals(str.substring(0, 1))) || !(" ".equals(str.substring(str.length() - 1)))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                count++;
            }
        }
        count = count + 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Split your string at the special characters and reverse each segment

Comment: @IanRehwinkel it is a bit trickier than that, he splits on empty space and then he concatenates adding the removed spaces. He would need to include logic to re-add the special characters.

Comment: When you say you need to retain the special characters where they are, what is the expected output when your string is `Sta'ck, Overflow.`? Is it `kc'atS, wolfrevO` or `kca'tS, wolfrevO`?

Comment: @Prasann i think it will print "kc'atS, wolfrevO."

Answer (score 0):

I've written up a little Python sketch that does what you wanted. I know it isn't Java, but the functionality is basic and should be easily translatable into java. I added some comments to guide you:

```py
def split(string, seperators):  # parameters dont have types in Python. Imagine (String string, String separators) here
    words = []

    while True:
        j = len(string)
        if j == 0:
            break
        for sc in seperators:  # iterate over all chars in seperators string
            try:
                i = string.index(sc)
                if i < j:
                    j = i
            except ValueError:  # This is like try-catch. ValueError is thrown when no value is found. Java returns -1 when str.indexOf(char) isn't found
                continue

        nextWord = string[:j]  # this means substring(0, j)
        if nextWord:
            words.append(nextWord)
        words.append(string[j:j+1])  # this means substring(j, j+1)
        string = string[j+1:]  # this means substring(j+1)
    return words


def reverse(string):  # Imagine (String string) here
    words = split(string, "., ")
    newWords = []  # eqivalent to: new ArrayList<String>();
    for w in words:
        if len(w) > 1:
            newWords.append(w[::-1])  # w[::-1] reverses a string in python
        else:
            newWords.append(w)  # append is like ArrayList.add(e)
    return "".join(newWords)  # this joins a list to a string. In java: String.join("", list);

print(reverse("stack, overflow."))
# output: kcats, wolfrevo.
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your input at the special characters keeping those in the resulting array using a regular expression; in your example above split at space char, comma and dot. Then reverse each element in the resulting array and concatenate them to a new string. Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "stack, overflow.";
    String[] splited = splitInput(input);
    String result = "";
    for(String s : splited){
        result += reverseString(s);
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static String[] splitInput(String input) {
    // [,\\. ] -> split at , . ' ' and keep the delimiters
    // this will produce for the example input [stack, ,,  , overflow, .]
    String regex = "((?<=[,\\. ])|(?=[,\\. ]))";
    return input.split(regex);
}
public static String reverseString(String str) {
    return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you should consider using here is a stack data structure instead of an array.
A stack has a FILO methodology -- the first item you put in, is the last item to come out. Consider something like a STACK of bricks, or pancakes. The first one placed is at the bottom.

```
Here is a little driver program to show you what I mean:
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 

class Test{    

    public static void main (String[] args){ 
        // creates a stack
        Stack<Integer> word_stack = new Stack<Integer>(); 

        // grab user input
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input a phrase");

        // conver it to an array
        String userInput = myScan.nextLine();
        char[] userInputArray = userInput.toCharArray();


        // pushes everything onto the stack
        for (int i = 0; i < userInputArray.length; i++){
            word_stack.stack_push(userInputArray[i]);
        }

        // pops it off
        for (i < 0; i < userInputArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(userInputArray[i]);
            word_stack.stack_pop();
        } //end for

    } //end psvm
} // end class
```

Answer (score 0):

As just the words should be reversed, and the interpunction remain, loop the characters and identify words, reverting them in-situ. This could be done by `str.toCharArray()`, or as here by a StringBuilder (as arrays probably are already known).

```
String str = input.nextLine();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
sb.setCharAt(0, Character.toLowerCase(sb.charAt(0)));
int wordBegin = -1;
int wordEnd = -1;
boolean inWord = false;
for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); ++i) {
    char ch = sb.charAt(i);
    boolean letter = Character.isLetter(ch);
    if (letter) {
        if (!inWord) {
            wordBegin = i;
            inWord = true;
        }
        wordEnd = i;
    } else {
        if (inWord) {
            inWord = false;
            reverse(sb, wordBegin, wordEnd);
        }
    }
}
if (inWord) {
    reverse(sb, wordBegin, wordEnd);
}
str = sb.toString();

/** @param to inclusive index. */
void reverse(StringBuilder sb, int from, int to) {
    while (from < to) {
        char fromCh = sb.charAt(from);
        char toCh = sb.charAt(to);
        sb.setCharAt(from, toCh);
        sb.setCharAt(to, fromCh);
        ++from;
        --to;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54630236/1036310) by @Eritrean to use lambda and streams:

```
String input = "stack, overflow.";
List<String> tokens = Arrays.asList(input
        .split("((?<=[,\\. ])|(?=[,\\. ]))"));
String result = tokens.stream()
        .map(s -> new StringBuilder(s).reverse())
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println("result: " + result);
```